# Unable to post to Spring Data Rest RepositoryRestResource in integration tests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

It doesn't appear in the integration tests that the resource links are exposed for my repositories. They appear fine when the application is running but during the test a POST to, what should be a valid uri, gives a 404 with the message

`The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.`

configuration

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@DirtiesContext
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = {ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class, AnsApplication.class, PostgreSQLConfiguration.class},
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT
)
@DataJpaTest
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"xxx.xxx.xxx"})
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
```

Note this configuration works fine for integration tests that save and retrieve entities using an injected repository, posting against the repository is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, there is some interaction with the `@DataJpaTest` annotation that also required adding `ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class` to the `@SpringBootTest` list. This created a container which did not have my endpoints registered.

Removing both `@DataJpaTest` and `ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class` from the configuration list allowed my integration tests using TestRestTemplate to work. For JPA specific tests I will add them back.